# Photos framework: UICollectionView scrolling jitter

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, thumbnails, smooth-scrolling, photosframework

I am using Photos framework and `requestImageForAsset:` taking too much time, and thus it really has very bad scrolling performance.

I tried by setting `PHImageRequestOptions` option as:

```
let options: PHImageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.FastFormat
```

The scrolling becomes totally smooth(**So I know this is the only causing factor**) but the thumbnail remains blurred as for `FastFormat` delivery option, `resultHandler:` will be called only once with degraded image quality.

Currently I am using following code(Which has a bad scrolling):

```
    // Size is proper as per scale i.e(ui-width * scale, uiheight * scale)
    self.imageManager?.requestImageForAsset(phAsset,
      targetSize: size,
      contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill,
         options: nil,
      resultHandler: { (resultImage, info) -> Void in

       // Call completion handler.
       completion(phAsset: phAsset, image: resultImage)
   })
```

**Anyone having any idea like how scrolling performance can be improved given the problem is in the above described method?**

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As per Apple documentation,

> If you need to load image data for many assets together, use the PHCachingImageManager class to “preheat” the cache by loading images you expect to need soon. For example, when populating a collection view with photo asset thumbnails, you can cache images ahead of the current scroll position

```
// Update the assets the PHCachingImageManager is caching.
    [self.imageManager startCachingImagesForAssets:assetsToStartCaching
                                        targetSize:AssetGridThumbnailSize
                                       contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                           options:nil];
    [self.imageManager stopCachingImagesForAssets:assetsToStopCaching
                                       targetSize:AssetGridThumbnailSize
                                      contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                          options:nil];
```

You can easily refer to caching help @Sample app provided by apple 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html